# Before redirecting altdomain to domain with .htaccess, should I register altdomain as alias or as addon?

Tags: .htaccess, cpanel, redirect

On cPanel Redirect page, the domain to redirect is chosen from a dropdown menu, which only lists domains already registered as alias or addons.

If my goal is to redirect altdomain to domain, should I register altdomain as an alias or as an addon? what's the difference?

There is no alternate content. On redirection the address bar should show the main domain (and use its SSL certif).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Redirects tool lists all domains that you have in your cPanel account - **Primary, Addon, Subdomain.**

By making a redirect from that tool, under the hood you're actually

1. Creating an .htaccess file in the Document Root for the domain
2. Making a redirect rule in the created .htaccess file

The answer to your question depends on **whether your domain that you wish to redirect to is your Primary Domain or an Addon Domain**

**If it's the Primary Domain** - I would recommend adding altdomain as an Alias. This will basically create a Alias in your vhost file which is more optimal that actually creating an HTTP redirect instead.

If it's an Addon / Subdomain - In this case you need to make a redirect through cPanel's interface.

After the redirect is done you can also force your domain to open with https:// in front using an .htaccess rule:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://yourdomain.com/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```